# Hide live boot partition on USB-HDD

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, live-usb, external-hdd

I installed a "live" Ubuntu 14.10 on my external harddrive.

I don't want it to be seen by other operating systems all the people get confused by the 2 partitions. Is this possible?

Comment: To close voters: this question is entirely independent of the Ubuntu release on the USB drive. It solely depends on the *other* OS trying to read the USB drive.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to “hide” a partition on a removable drives from Windows, since it only looks at the first partition on them. Not all external drive announce themselves as such. If Windows believes, that the external drive is a regular hard drive, it will list all partitions anyhow.

Here's how I did it on my USB flash drive:

1. Re-partition your external drive (e. g. with GParted):

   1. Shrink the first (and only) partition on your external drive or delete it and create a smaller one in its stead. Leave enough space after its end for Ubuntu (1.5 GB should be enough, if you just want a plain live system that doesn't retain changes between boots). You can put whatever you want on this partition, since it's irrelevant for the Ubuntu live system, that you're going to install later on.
   2. Create a second partition for Ubuntu. If you don't need to access it with Windows, you can format it with ext4 instead of FAT32.
2. Install [UNetbootin](//apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unetbootin/) and run it. It will ask for a password for super-user privileges.
3. Select the correct disk image for the Ubuntu live system installation, set the drive type to “USB drive” and select the *2nd partition* on it as the drive (here: `/dev/sdg2`). Note the `2` at the end of the device name. If you have more partitions on the drive, you can select those too, as long as they're not the first.

   [image: UNetbootin screenshot]
4. Click the OK button and let UNetbootin do its job.

Comment: As you're (nearly) a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!